# Can I cheat the docker run -it session by remapping ctrl+p key?

Tags: bash, terminal, emacs, docker

This is regarding this issue with docker: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/3519 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828657/docker-change-ctrlp-to-something-else

As I understand this, the docker run -it command opens an interactive terminal and this terminal has special meaning for Ctrl-P + Ctrl-Q combination (detaches from the container). This messes up with the bash and emacs shortcuts when you are inside the container. I've to press Ctrl-P twice for the Ctrl-P to reach bash or emacs.

Is there any way to workaround this (other than re-compiling docker itself) by some kind of terminal/bash keybinding magic?

What I'm specifically trying to see is if there is some way where by remapping keys, pressing Ctrl-J (anything other than Ctrl-P for that matter) will be read by the docker terminal as Ctrl-P. More importantly, I want to remap Ctrl-P itself to something else, say Ctrl-L. So whenever I press Ctrl-P, the docker container would receive Ctrl-L. And then I can program bash/emacs inside the docker container to map Ctrl-L to the command corresponding to Ctrl-P (move to previous command/line).

In short,
I press Ctrl-P, the docker session receives it as Ctrl-L and passes it along to emacs, emacs maps Ctrl-L to the command corresponding to Ctrl-P.

Is this even a reasonable ask?

I would be glad if there is some other relatively easy workaround for the original problem.

I'm using OS X's Terminal app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41820108/ctrl-p-and-ctrl-n-behaving-unexpectedly-under-docker